# Passing multiple POST parameters with the same parameter name

Tags: javascript, php, post, url-rewriting, get

I have a scenario where I need to send some POST parameters but with the same name how can I do it?
I have a similar scenario with a GET as well in which I could simply construct the URL by appending the same parameter name  but how can I do it with POST.
If it was for GET it would be something like

```
          $url=$url."&team=".$name1;
          $url=$url."&team=".$name2;
```

But how can I do the same with POST?
Any help is appreciated 
I tried searching for it but couldn't find an appropriate answer

thanks in advance

Comment: How are you forming the post params? Can you share the markup or whatever?

Comment: @Subhanker Yes 
to be exact this happens in an intermediate page so there is no user activity happening in this php page

Comment: If you use the same parameter name, each one is going to overwrite the previous one, which means that you'll get just the last one. Unless you're using an array parameter (something like `team[]=1&team[]=2`, etc)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I receive the data as POST parameter and as a comma separated string from a different page and I explode tat based on the comma to separate it out and have individual values

Comment: @Uby and when it come to retrieving the parameter will it have to be iterated through a loop as individual array values??

Comment: @Gotham'sReckoning Yes

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use `hidden` fields inside form data to send an Value as POST like

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="value">
```

In Case you don't want any user activity You can use Javascript to submit form:

```
<form action="http://example.com/foo" name="hiddenform" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="value1">
    <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="value2">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout("document.forms['hiddenform'].submit();",0);
</script>
```

Above Will Display Nothing on Screen and submit form as soon as this loads.

*Side-Note:* if you want to delay change value of `0` according to your needs in `setTimeout("document.forms['hiddenform'].submit();",0);`

Comment: I had mentioned there are no user activity happening nor it has any form elements

Comment: Updated My Answer Hopefully It Will Help.

Comment: Subhanker Thanks for that. I had tried that for some other scenario.I was actually wondering whether I could do it without the use of form. Apparently I got the answer from the comments from @Uby as It could be passed in as an array. thanks anyways :)

Comment: Just keep in mind that user can edit the form if he wants to.

Comment: @TomášZato indeed, but most of the users wont even notice any form submit as it happens as soon as the page loads but ofcource someone with an geeky mind can manipulate the data and OP or whoever uses this must be concerned of.

Answer (score 0):

If you *need* the values passed through a browser address bar, you need to form the link this way:

```
$url = "team=".$name1.",".$name2;
```

Then in the main PHP code you may `explode` it into array chunks:

```
$urlArray = explode(",", $url);
```

Comment: U r talking about GET and what I was asking was POST

Comment: @Gotham'sReckoning POST is using the same data encoding normally. It only changes when you're sending files. Here is [an answer explaining POST format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14551320/607407). Both PHP and Javascript have functions that allow you to generate the requests.